# Oocharts - desperate call for assistance

Tags: javascript, analytics

I'm trying to use the Oocharts API to display my Google Analytics Data and everything I've been trying ends up in a white screen. Below is the code I'm using according to their site's examples:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>With JS</h3>
    <div id='chart'></div>

    <h3>With HTML Attributes</h3>
    <div data-oochart='bar' data-oochart-start-date='30d' data-oochart-metrics='ga:visits,Visits,ga:newVisits,New Visits' data-oochart-dimension='ga:continent' data-oochart-profile='ga:84157823'></div>

    <script src='../oocharts.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function(){

            oo.setAPIKey("61a7a03dcab1487aa4ba3126f10e275f219d03c6");

            oo.load(function(){

                var bar = new oo.Bar("ga:84157823", "30d");

                bar.addMetric("ga:visits", "Visits");

                bar.addMetric("ga:newVisits", "New Visits");

                bar.setDimension("ga:continent");

                bar.draw('chart');

            });
        };

    </script>
</body>
```

At the oo.setAPIKey() function I tried both Oocharts Mission Control's API key and the Google Analytics API Key (cause I wasn't so sure which one to use) with the same, empty, results.

Please give me an answer to what I'm doing wrong here cause I'm going crazy. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Can you add any error reports you get? That will help people answer your question.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. That's the strange part. Just a blank screen...

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might be interested:
At the oo.setAPIKey function you use the API key provided by the Oocharts Mission Control.
At the oo.Bar you use just the number of your profile id, not ga: and then the number.
And of course at the bar.draw('chart') you replace 'chart' with 'bar'.

Hope this will prevent someone (like me) from throwing his head to the wall ;)...